# I want to do a search replace in perl. My file has strings like "time1", "+time1", "+time11", "time11".How do I differentiate between these 4 strings

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace

```
if ($search =~ /\W/){ #if search pattern has any special character
        $sentence =~ s/\Q$search\E\b/$replace/g; #\Q..\E will consider special characters. \b is for word boundary
    }
    else {
        $sentence =~ s/\b$search\b/$replace/g; #no need \Q..\E if not spl characters
    }
}
print $sentence;
```

the else part is causing a problem as it is replacing +time1 as well as time1. Is there a single regex expression to take care of this situation so that I need not use if else?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67146072/372239) and add some sentences and expected result.

Comment: I am guessing that your problem is that your regex does a partial substitution where it should not, e.g. it changes `time1` before it changes `time11+`. You really should show us what your strings look like that you want to perform these replacements on.

Answer (score 3):

```perl
my %map = (
   "time1"   => "...",
   "+time1"  => "...",
   "time11"  => "...",
   "+time11" => "...",
);

my $pat =
   join "|",
      map quotemeta,
         sort { length($b) <=> length($a) }
            keys(%map);

s/($pat)/$map{$1}/g
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use Data::Dumper;
    
    $text = 'time1+............time1.............time11.............+time11...............';
    
    print Dumper $text;
    
    $text =~ s/(.*)(time1)([^0-9].*)/$1$3/g;
    
    print Dumper $text;
```

Output is:

```
$VAR1 = 'time1+............time1.............time11.............+time11...............';
$VAR1 = 'time1+.........................time11.............+time11...............';
```

If depends on the expected results.
Alternatively, to replace only time1:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl
    use Data::Dumper;
    
    $text = '............time1............+time1.............time11.............+time11...............';
    
    print Dumper $text;
    
    $text =~ s/(.*)([^\+]time1)([^0-9].*)/$1$3/g;
    
    print Dumper $text;
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = '............time1............+time1.............time11.............+time11...............';
$VAR1 = '.......................+time1.............time11.............+time11...............';
```